# Can cookies collect my entire browsing history?

Tags: cookies

Can any cookies collect my entire browsing history when they're dropped?
I use CCleaner to remove all cookies after I close browser, exceptions are the sites I have accounts.

Comment: Not at all. There are different options in CCleaner to delete cookies or browsing history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Cookies have a couple of limitations:

> The cookie specifications require that browsers meet the following
>   requirements in order to support cookies:
>
> - Can support cookies as large as 4,096 bytes in size.
> - Can support at least 50 cookies per domain (i.e. per website).
> - Can support at least 3,000 cookies in total.

[wikipedia:HTTP Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Your history will - if at all - be aggregated on the servers of those that are setting those cookies on your machine. So hacking all those machines and matching the stolen data to your identifier (inside the cookie) is required to expose your history. Much easier to hack your machine and read out the history directly from your browser ;-)

Comment: Can cookies from all sites I visit collect, even if it's anonymous, aggerated?